# Select md-tab by text of label

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, angular-material

Is there a way to get the md-tab by label text?

I'm currently using:

```
element(by.css('md-tab-item:nth-child(2)')).click().then(function() {
  //do something
});
```

to get the `About` tab:

```
<md-tabs>
  <md-tab label="Home"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="About"></md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Contact"></md-tab>
</md-tabs>
```

But I've found I've been adding / removing tabs so this isn't the optimal way to accomplish finding a tab with a specific label...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `element(by.css('md-tab[label=About]'))`

Comment: Good thought @shakib, but that's the tricky part, the label isn't what is rendered to the view (inspect element on one of the tabs [HERE](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)).

Comment: Jsut fiddling, with [reference](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.xpath), can you try it like `element(by.xpath('//md-tab-item[span="About"]')`?

Comment: Do those `md-tab`'s have a child element, or is it exactly as you posted above?  in the link you provided, they contain a span with text.  If yes, you could grab the child and traverse up to the parent with xpath, `element(by.cssContainingText('span', 'Home')).element(by.xpath('..'));`

Comment: Actually none of those work :/ @shakib

Comment: ^ same @Gunderson